# Solving $\beta - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\sec{\beta}=2$ for $180^\circ\leq\beta\leq 270^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry

I am required to solve this equation:

> Solve
> $$\beta - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\sec{\beta}=2$$
> for $180^\circ\leq\beta\leq 270^\circ$.

I am aware that I can convert $\sec{\beta}=\frac{1}{\cos{\beta}}$.

So,
$$\beta - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\sec{\beta}=2$$
$$\sqrt{3}\beta - \sec{\beta}=2\sqrt{3}$$
$$\sqrt{3}\beta - \frac{1}{\cos{\beta}}=2\sqrt{3}$$
$$\sqrt{3}\beta \cos{\beta} - 1=2\sqrt{3} \cos{\beta}$$
$$\sqrt{3}\beta \cos{\beta} - 2\sqrt{3} \cos{\beta}=1$$
$$(\beta-2)\sqrt{3} \cos{\beta} =1$$

.. I stuck here.

If anyone can explain to me how to achieve this I would be very grateful.

Comment: [No such value exists](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x-%28sec+x%29%2F%5Csqrt3%3D2)

Comment: Are you sure you have written down the question properly? Should there be a trig function applied to the first $\beta$? Generally speaking, it is hard to find exact results to questions which combine an angle with a trig function of the angle.